# Datasets name as strings and how to evaluate them

Tags: r, eval

I know how to eval a string, so I can use it as variable.

But I don't know how to 'eval' a string to use it as dataset.

My problem:

I have different datasets with the same structure. The names of the datasets are for example data010 to data019.
I want to bind them (via bind_rows).

This is not working:

```
for (i %in% c(10:19)){
   if (i == 1)
      df <- eval(paste("data0",i)) # eval(parse(paste("data0",i))) is also not working
    else
      df <- df %>% bind_rows(eval(paste("data0",i)))
}
```

So how to `eval` a dataset's name given as string?

Comment: Try `bind_rows(mget(paste0("data0", 10:19)))`

Comment: Yikes. How did you wind up with a bunch of variables named `data010`, `data011`, `data012` etc? Sounds like those values probably should have been read into a list in R. Then it would be much easier to work with them. When code is written in an R-like way, you very rarely ever need `eval`, `get`, or `assign`. I think the real problem here is how you've read in the data.

Comment: @MrFlick: yes youre right. Maybe it is a little bit more complicated: The datasets I want to combine are the data of different years. I want to read them in to a shiny app to viziualise trend over time. I don't think it is possible to store the several RData-files into a list. But maybe I'm just not familiar with that :-)

Comment: @akrun: Thats it. Thankyou.